# npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":{"shasum":"ae6c2edf'

Tags: npm, angular-cli-v6

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":{"shasum":"ae6c2edf' 
>   getting this error while npm install.

Steps i had done
1. create a new project
2. done npm install

getting this error for all new projects.

Answer (score 6):

Cleaning the corrupted local npm cache may fix this error.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Just run your npm command again after executing the above command in your terminal.

---

There could be few other reasons for the invalid JSON, as described in the official documentation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/common-errors#invalid-json).

The official `npm` website has well documented most of the common errors. But unfortunately they don’t appear on the top results when you google the error.

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

updating angular cli to latest worked for me.